# Remove both the object if found duplicate in scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have an Seq with the following Object

case class Foo (age: Int, name: String)

val x = List(Foo(30,"X"), Foo(30,"Y"),Foo(40,"Z"),Foo(50,"X"))

I want to check the list for duplicates and remove them from the list. In this case my list will only have one values, and in this example it would be the values Foo(40,"Z"), and the three Foo(30,"X") ,Foo(30,"Y") and Foo(50,"X") will go away.

Because X and 3O is repeated in some object

What will be the best way to this?

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers.groupBy(identity)
    .filter(_._2.size == 1)
    .keys
```

Something like this.

Comment: can you please provide full working scala code.If it is case class then it will fail

Comment: I’ve given you enough “working code”, I’m not going to do your job. For case class, all you need to do is change how you group, shouldn’t be hard to figure that out.